# Not sure on his format, I have to figure out which mapping is not linear

Tags: linear-algebra

We have L:$C^0 \to \mathbb{R}$, $L(f) = f\left(\frac12\right)$.  He wants to know if this is linear.

Is his formatting indicating no matter who I pick for $L(x)$ it will equal $\frac12$?  IF I pick L(5) = 1/2 always

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax references.

Comment: Whose format?  What is this question even about?!

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is a function from $C^0$.

$L$ is a mapping that maps $f$ to a real value, that particular value is chosen to be $f(0.5)$.

Comment: So am I correct in saying not linear because f(3 + 4) is not equal to f(3) + f(4).....f(7) =f(.5) + f(.5)?

Comment: hmm... u didn't use anything about $L$ in your working, so the argument can't be right. take two function $f,g \in C^0$, inspect if $L(f+g)=L(f)+L(g)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have for $f,g$ continuous functions, $a,b$ constants
$$
L(af+bg)=(af+bg)(1/2)=af(1/2)+bg(1/2)
$$
by the way we understand summing two functions $f$ and $g$.